# C++ parallel merge sort

Tags: c++, beginner, multithreading, sorting, mergesort

I'm a first year computer engineering student who's learning about algorithms and data structures. I've implemented a parallel merge sort algorithm in C++ and would like constructive criticism. This was done in Visual Studio on Windows.

**Some thoughts:**

- portability isn't a concern I have atm.
- `merge_sort` isn't using tail recursion, which I would like it to do

---

**includes:**
`#include <thread>`

**function merge:**

```
template<typename T>
void merge(T sequence[], int size)
{
    T* sorted = new T[size];
    int middle = size / 2;

    int index_left = 0;
    int index_right = middle;
    int index_sequence = 0;

    while (index_left < middle && index_right < size)
    {
        if (sequence[index_left] < sequence[index_right])
            sorted[index_sequence++] = sequence[index_left++];
        else
            sorted[index_sequence++] = sequence[index_right++];
    }

    while (index_left < middle)
        sorted[index_sequence++] = sequence[index_left++];

    while (index_right < size)
        sorted[index_sequence++] = sequence[index_right++];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        sequence[i] = sorted[i];

    delete[] sorted;
}
```

**function merge_sort:**

```
template<typename T, int min_size_to_thread = 10000>
void merge_sort(T sequence[], int size)
{
    if (size > 1)
    {
        int middle = size / 2;
        if (size > min_size_to_thread)
        {
            std::thread left(merge_sort<T, min_size_to_thread>, &sequence[0], middle);
            std::thread right(merge_sort<T, min_size_to_thread>, &sequence[middle], size - middle);
            left.join();
            right.join();
        }
        else
        {
            merge_sort<T, min_size_to_thread>(&sequence[0], middle);
            merge_sort<T, min_size_to_thread>(&sequence[middle], size - middle);
        }
        merge<T>(sequence, size);
    }
}
```

---

For those who are interested: I Did some performance testing on a i5-2530M 2.50Ghz (2 cores).
The sequence to merge sort is `int[100000]`

---

**Edit:**

I made `merge_sort` and `merge` take a `T tmp[]`. And I made a "wrapper" function around `merge_sort` like this:

```
template<typename T>
void merge_sort(T* sequence, int size)
{
    T* tmp = new T[size];
    _merge_sort(sequence, tmp, size);
    delete[] tmp;
}
```

Now `new` is only called once. The "old" `merge_sort` is renamed to `_merge_sort`.

Comment: Is `std::thread right` redundant?

Comment: **I've tested:** `merge_sort` runs faster *without* threading `right`, so it's better to only thread `left` and let right run in the main thread.

Comment: for an array of `100000` elements, you're calling `new` about `100000` times... that will not be efficient

Comment: @MartinYork Remember that the size of the sequence is halfed for each recursive call. E.g. with `min_size_to_thread = 50000` only 1 extra thread is made.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's my parallel merge sort. It's a class with thread-pooling and attached to each thread there is a sort buffer which is recycled when a standby-thread gets another segment to sort; this ensures that the thread works with its memory already lying in the most local caches. The code uses the thread with the most-fitting sort-buffer or when all standby-threads have to small sort-buffers, one thread is arbitrarily chosen and the size of the sort-buffer is adjusted accordingly.

The class is instantiated once with the predicate and you can call .sort() multiple times with the thread- and buffer-pool recycled for each call. Or you can create a temporary object and then call .sort on it, i.e. call parallel_merge_sort().sort( ... ).

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <algorithm>
#include <utility>
#include <exception>
#include <cassert>
#include <iterator>

template<typename T>
struct invoke_on_destruct
{
private:
    T    &m_t;
    bool  m_enabled;

public:
    invoke_on_destruct( T &t ) :
        m_t( t ), m_enabled( true )
    {
    }

    ~invoke_on_destruct()
    {
        if( m_enabled )
            m_t();
    }

    void invoke_and_disable()
    {
        m_t();
        m_enabled = false;
    }
};

struct sort_exception : public std::exception
{
};

template<typename InputIt, typename P = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>>
class parallel_merge_sort
{
public:
                parallel_merge_sort( P const &p = P() );
                ~parallel_merge_sort();
    void        sort( InputIt itBegin, size_t n, std::size_t minThreaded );
    std::size_t get_buffer_size();
    void        empty_buffers();

private:
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type value_type;
    typedef typename std::vector<value_type>                   buffer_type;
    typedef typename buffer_type::iterator                     buffer_iterator;

    struct pool_thread
    {
        enum CMD : int { CMD_STOP = -1, CMD_NONE = 0, CMD_SORT    = 1 };
        enum RSP : int { RSP_ERR  = -1, RSP_NONE = 0, RSP_SUCCESS = 1 };

        std::thread             m_thread;
        std::mutex              m_mtx;
        std::condition_variable m_sigInitiate;
        CMD                     m_cmd;
        buffer_iterator         m_itBegin;
        std::size_t             m_n;
        std::condition_variable m_sigResponse;
        RSP                     m_rsp;
        std::vector<value_type> m_sortBuf;

                           pool_thread( parallel_merge_sort *pPMS );
                           ~pool_thread();
        void               sort_thread( parallel_merge_sort *pPMS );
        static std::size_t calc_buffer_size( size_t n );
    };

    P                      m_p;
    std::size_t            m_minThreaded;
    unsigned               m_maxRightThreads;
    buffer_type            m_callerSortBuf;
    std::mutex             m_mtxPool;
    std::list<pool_thread> m_standbyThreads;
    std::list<pool_thread> m_activeThreads;

    template<typename InputIt2>
    void threaded_sort( InputIt2 itBegin, std::size_t n, buffer_iterator itSortBuf );
    template<typename InputIt2>
    void unthreaded_sort( InputIt2 itBegin, std::size_t n, buffer_iterator itSortBuf );
    template<typename OutputIt>
    void merge_back( OutputIt itUp, buffer_iterator itLeft, buffer_iterator itLeftEnd, buffer_iterator itRight, buffer_iterator itRightEnd );
};

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::parallel_merge_sort( P const &p ) :
    m_p( p )
{
    unsigned hc = std::thread::hardware_concurrency();
    m_maxRightThreads = hc != 0 ? (hc - 1) : 0;
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::sort( InputIt itBegin, size_t n, std::size_t minThreaded )
{
    size_t const MIN_SIZE = 2;
    if( n < MIN_SIZE )
        return;
    if( (m_minThreaded = minThreaded) < (2 * MIN_SIZE) )
        m_minThreaded = 2 * MIN_SIZE;
    try
    {
        std::size_t s = pool_thread::calc_buffer_size( n );
        if( m_callerSortBuf.size() < s )
            m_callerSortBuf.resize( s );
        threaded_sort( itBegin, n, m_callerSortBuf.begin() );
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        throw sort_exception();
    }
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::~parallel_merge_sort()
{
    assert(m_activeThreads.size() == 0);
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
std::size_t parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::pool_thread::calc_buffer_size( std::size_t n )
{
    for( std::size_t rest = n, right; rest > 2; )
        right  = rest - (rest / 2),
        n     += right,
        rest   = right;
    return n;
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::pool_thread::~pool_thread()
{
    using namespace std;
    unique_lock<mutex> threadLock( m_mtx );
    m_cmd = pool_thread::CMD_STOP;
    m_sigInitiate.notify_one();
    threadLock.unlock();
    m_thread.join();
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
template<typename InputIt2>
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::threaded_sort( InputIt2 itBegin, std::size_t n, buffer_iterator itSortBuf )
{
    using namespace std;
    unique_lock<mutex> poolLock( m_mtxPool );

    if( n < m_minThreaded || (m_standbyThreads.empty() && m_activeThreads.size() >= m_maxRightThreads) )
    {
        poolLock.unlock();
        unthreaded_sort( itBegin, n, itSortBuf );
        return;
    }

    typedef typename list<pool_thread>::iterator pt_it;
    pt_it        itPT;
    pool_thread *pPT;
    size_t       left  = n / 2,
                 right = n - left;
    if( !m_standbyThreads.empty() )
    {
        pt_it  itPTScan;
        size_t optimalSize = pool_thread::calc_buffer_size( right ),
               bestFit     = (size_t)(ptrdiff_t)-1,
               size;
        for( itPT = m_standbyThreads.end(), itPTScan = m_standbyThreads.begin();
             itPTScan != m_standbyThreads.end(); ++itPTScan )
            if( (size = itPTScan->m_sortBuf.size()) >= optimalSize && size < bestFit )
                itPT    = itPTScan,
                bestFit = size;
        if( itPT == m_standbyThreads.end() )
            itPT = --m_standbyThreads.end();
        m_activeThreads.splice( m_activeThreads.end(), m_standbyThreads, itPT );
        poolLock.unlock();
        pPT = &*itPT;
    }
    else
        m_activeThreads.emplace_back( this ),
        itPT = --m_activeThreads.end(),
        pPT = &*itPT,
        poolLock.unlock();

    auto pushThreadBack = [&poolLock, &itPT, this]()
        {
            poolLock.lock();
            m_standbyThreads.splice( m_standbyThreads.end(), m_activeThreads, itPT );
        };
    invoke_on_destruct<decltype(pushThreadBack)> autoPushBackThread( pushThreadBack );

    buffer_iterator itMoveTo = itSortBuf;
    for( InputIt2 itMoveFrom = itBegin, itEnd = itMoveFrom + n; itMoveFrom != itEnd; *itMoveTo = move( *itMoveFrom ), ++itMoveTo, ++itMoveFrom );

    buffer_iterator    itLeft  = itSortBuf,
                       itRight = itLeft + left;
    unique_lock<mutex> threadLock( pPT->m_mtx );
    pPT->m_cmd     = pool_thread::CMD_SORT;
    pPT->m_rsp     = pool_thread::RSP_NONE;
    pPT->m_itBegin = itRight;
    pPT->m_n       = right;
    pPT->m_sigInitiate.notify_one();
    threadLock.unlock();

    auto waitForThread = [&threadLock, pPT]()
        {
            threadLock.lock();
            while( pPT->m_rsp == pool_thread::RSP_NONE )
                pPT->m_sigResponse.wait( threadLock );
            assert(pPT->m_rsp == pool_thread::RSP_SUCCESS || pPT->m_rsp == pool_thread::RSP_ERR);
        };
    invoke_on_destruct<decltype(waitForThread)> autoWaitForThread( waitForThread );

    threaded_sort( itLeft, left, itSortBuf + n );

    autoWaitForThread.invoke_and_disable();
    if( pPT->m_rsp == pool_thread::RSP_ERR )
        throw sort_exception();
    threadLock.unlock();

    merge_back( itBegin, itLeft, itLeft + left, itRight, itRight + right );
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
template<typename InputIt2>
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::unthreaded_sort( InputIt2 itBegin, std::size_t n, buffer_iterator itSortBuf )
{
    assert(n >= 2);
    using namespace std;
    if( n == 2 )
    {
        if( m_p( itBegin[1], itBegin[0] ) )
        {
            value_type temp( move( itBegin[0] ) );
            itBegin[0] = move( itBegin[1] );
            itBegin[1] = move( temp );
        }
        return;
    }

    buffer_iterator itMoveTo = itSortBuf;
    for( InputIt2 itMoveFrom = itBegin, itEnd = itMoveFrom + n; itMoveFrom != itEnd; *itMoveTo = move( *itMoveFrom ), ++itMoveTo, ++itMoveFrom );

    size_t          left   = n / 2,
                    right  = n - left;
    buffer_iterator itLeft  = itSortBuf,
                    itRight = itLeft + left;
    if( left >= 2 )
        unthreaded_sort( itLeft,  left,  itSortBuf + n );
    if( right >= 2 )
        unthreaded_sort( itRight, right, itSortBuf + n );
    merge_back( itBegin, itLeft, itLeft + left, itRight, itRight + right );
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
template<typename OutputIt>
inline
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::merge_back( OutputIt itUp, buffer_iterator itLeft, buffer_iterator itLeftEnd, buffer_iterator itRight, buffer_iterator itRightEnd )
{
    assert(itLeft < itLeftEnd && itRight < itRightEnd);
    using namespace std;
    for( ; ; )
        if( m_p( *itLeft, *itRight ) )
        {
            *itUp = move( *itLeft );
            ++itUp, ++itLeft;
            if( itLeft == itLeftEnd )
            {
                for( ; itRight != itRightEnd; *itUp = move( *itRight ), ++itUp, ++itRight );
                break;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            *itUp = move( *itRight );
            ++itUp, ++itRight;
            if( itRight == itRightEnd )
            {
                for( ; itLeft != itLeftEnd; *itUp = move( *itRight ), ++itUp, ++itLeft );
                break;
            }
        }
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
std::size_t parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::get_buffer_size()
{
    std::size_t s = 0;
    for( pool_thread &pt : m_standbyThreads )
        s += pt.m_sortBuf.capacity();
    return s + m_callerSortBuf.capacity();
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::empty_buffers()
{
    for( pool_thread &pt : m_standbyThreads )
        pt.m_sortBuf.clear(),
        pt.m_sortBuf.shrink_to_fit();
    m_callerSortBuf.clear();
    m_callerSortBuf.shrink_to_fit();
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::pool_thread::pool_thread( parallel_merge_sort *pPMS ) :
    m_mtx(),
    m_sigInitiate(),
    m_cmd( pool_thread::CMD_NONE ),
    m_thread( std::thread( []( pool_thread *pPT, parallel_merge_sort *pPMS ) -> void { pPT->sort_thread( pPMS ); }, this, pPMS ) )
{
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
void parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::pool_thread::sort_thread( parallel_merge_sort *pPMS )
{
    using namespace std;
    for( ; ; )
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> threadLock( m_mtx );
        while( m_cmd == CMD_NONE )
            m_sigInitiate.wait( threadLock );
        if( m_cmd == CMD_STOP )
            return;
        assert(m_cmd == pool_thread::CMD_SORT);
        m_cmd = CMD_NONE;
        threadLock.unlock();
        bool success;
        try
        {
            size_t size = calc_buffer_size( m_n );
            if( m_sortBuf.size() < size )
                m_sortBuf.resize( size );
            pPMS->threaded_sort( m_itBegin, m_n, m_sortBuf.begin() );
            success = true;
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            success = false;
        }
        threadLock.lock();
        m_rsp = success ? RSP_SUCCESS : RSP_ERR,
        m_sigResponse.notify_one();
    }
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type>>
class ref_parallel_merge_sort
{
private:
    struct ref
    {
        InputIt it;
    };

    struct ref_predicate
    {
        ref_predicate( P p );
        bool operator ()( ref const &left, ref const &right );
        P m_p;
    };

public:
                ref_parallel_merge_sort( P const &p = P() );
    void        sort( InputIt itBegin, size_t n, std::size_t maxUnthreaded );
    std::size_t get_buffer_size();
    void        empty_buffers();

private:
    parallel_merge_sort<ref, ref_predicate> m_sorter;
};

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::ref_predicate::ref_predicate( P p ) :
    m_p ( p )
{
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
bool ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::ref_predicate::operator ()( ref const &left, ref const &right )
{
    return m_p( *left.it, *right.it );
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::ref_parallel_merge_sort( P const &p ) :
    m_sorter( ref_predicate( p ) )
{
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
void ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::sort( InputIt itBegin, size_t n, std::size_t maxUnthreaded )
{
    using namespace std;
    try
    {
        typedef typename iterator_traits<InputIt>::value_type value_type;
        vector<ref> refBuf;
        InputIt     it;
        int         i;

        refBuf.resize( n );
        for( i = 0, it = itBegin; i != n; refBuf[i].it = it, ++i, ++it );
        m_sorter.sort( &refBuf[0], n, maxUnthreaded );

        vector<value_type> reorderBuf;
        reorderBuf.resize( n );
        for( i = 0, it = itBegin; i != n; reorderBuf[i] = move( *it ),           ++i, ++it );
        for( i = 0, it = itBegin; i != n; *it           = move( reorderBuf[i] ), ++i, ++it );
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        throw sort_exception();
    }
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
std::size_t ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::get_buffer_size()
{
    return m_sorter.get_buffer_size();
}

template<typename InputIt, typename P>
inline
void ref_parallel_merge_sort<InputIt, P>::empty_buffers()
{
    m_sorter.empty_buffers();
}

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <functional>
#include <random>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iterator>
#include <type_traits>

#if defined(_MSC_VER)
    #include <Windows.h>

double get_usecs()
{
    LONGLONG liTime;
    GetSystemTimeAsFileTime( &(FILETIME &)liTime );
    return (double)liTime / 10.0;
}
#elif defined(__unix__)
    #include <sys/time.h>

double get_usecs()
{
    timeval tv;
    gettimeofday( &tv, nullptr );
    return (double)tv.tv_sec * 1'000'000.0 + tv.tv_usec;
}
#elif
    #error no OS-support for get_usecs()
#endif

using namespace std;

void fill_with_random( double *p, size_t n, unsigned seed = 0 )
{
    default_random_engine re( seed );
    uniform_real_distribution<double> distrib;
    for( double *pEnd = p + n; p != pEnd; *p++ = distrib( re ) );
}

template<typename T, typename = typename enable_if<is_unsigned<T>::value, T>::type>
string decimal_unsigned( T t );

int main()
{
    typedef typename vector<double>::iterator it_type;
    size_t const   SIZE = (size_t)1024 * 1024 * 1024 / sizeof(double);
    unsigned       hc   = thread::hardware_concurrency();
    vector<double> v;
    double         t;

    hc = hc ? hc : 1;
    v.resize( SIZE );

    parallel_merge_sort<it_type> sd;

    fill_with_random( &v[0], SIZE );
    t = get_usecs();
    sd.sort( v.begin(), SIZE, SIZE / hc );
    t = get_usecs() - t;
    cout << (t / 1'000'000.0) << " seconds parallel" << endl;
    cout << decimal_unsigned( sd.get_buffer_size() * sizeof(double) ) << endl;
    sd.empty_buffers();

    fill_with_random( &v[0], SIZE );
    t = get_usecs();
    sd.sort( v.begin(), SIZE, SIZE );
    t = get_usecs() - t;
    cout << (t / 1'000'000.0) << " seconds sequential" << endl;
    cout << decimal_unsigned( sd.get_buffer_size() * sizeof(double) ) << endl;
    sd.empty_buffers();
}

#include <sstream>

string decify_string( string const &s );

template<typename T, typename>
string decimal_unsigned( T t )
{
    using namespace std;
    ostringstream oss;
    return move( decify_string( (oss << t, oss.str()) ) );
}

string decify_string( string const &s )
{
    using namespace std;
    ostringstream oss;
    size_t        length   = s.length(),
                  head     = length % 3,
                  segments = length / 3;
    if( head == 0 && segments >= 1 )
        head = 3,
        --segments;
    oss << s.substr( 0, head );
    for( size_t i = head; i != length; i += 3 )
        oss << "." << s.substr( i, 3 );
    return move( oss.str() );
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You would hava a) thread-pools so that the code won't spawn a new thread on each sub-sort, b) a limit on the number of sorts split into threads so that there isn't a new thread spawned for a low number of elements and c) a single array where all the sorting takes place and which is paritioned like a stack among the sort-threads (afaik the whole length should be two times the size of the array).

That would be a much of work to gain an efficient implementation.

Comment: a) can you show how? b) `min_size_to_thread` is the limit. c) that's smart